# 500 Internal server error after changing php version

Tags: php, 500-internal-error, internal-server-error

I recently uploaded a new wordpress website on a hosting service (with cpanel). I tried to change the php version because the wp theme gave me some errors on mobile but after i changed the php version the site went down with the 500 internal server errors.

I deleted the plugin folder, reset the htaccess, reupload wp-content and wp-includes but nothing happened.

This is the error log: [Thu Oct 06 05:17:16 2016] [alert] [client 188.11.159.103] /home/website/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://website.com/

But i checked my .htaccess and it's ok 
Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you simply tried removing your .htaccess file?  Back it up first of course.  IMO, you have a syntax error in there.  Why dont you post the contents?  .htaccess usually do not hold any sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

htaccess was my first thought. Since you've checked that, I'd move on to the apache error log. If you can't access this yourself your host should be able to help you.

Comment: There is a way to access to apache error log from cpanel?
i'm looking into Error Logs in the Advanced section

Comment: I don't have one to check, but this page should tell you: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/locations-of-common-log-files-on-cpanel-servers/

Comment: Unfortunately i can't find the folder this page is telling me

Comment: My next step would be to try really basic stuff (e.g. accessing static items; accessing a separate PHP script that just echoes out some text)

Comment: Thank you Jonny but i'm really noob about php and those server stuff. Do you think the only way is to speak to the server admin?

Comment: Do you have WP_DEBUG and errors turned on in your wp_config?  If not i'd do that first. Once you're in a position to debug, it will probably be something simple.  If you can't get anything to print the screen, yes, I think I'd ask the host to provide an exerpt from the log so you can figure out what's going on.  Cheers.